# Creating a JSON array containing multiple variables

Tags: arrays, json, perl

I want to modify my Perl script to output a list of variables using the **json_encode** function, but I'm not sure how.

Here's the output of my unmodified Perl script:

```
Vicia_sativa = Vicia_sativa.png 
Geranium_maculatum = Geranium_maculatum.png 
Narcissus_pseudonarcissus = Narcissus_pseudonarcissus1.png Narcissus_pseudonarcissus2.png 
Polygonum_persicaria = Polygonum_persicaria1.png Polygonum_persicaria2.png 
Corylus_americana = Corylus_americana1.png Corylus_americana2.png
```

The variables to the left of the equal signs are plant names, and the one or more file names to the right of the equal signs are plant photos. Notice that these file names are not separated by commas.

Here's my Perl script that generated the above output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use English;   ## use names rather than symbols for special variables

my $dir = '/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants';

opendir my $dfh, $dir  or die "Can't open $dir: $OS_ERROR";
my %genus_species;  ## store matching entries in a hash

for my $file (readdir $dfh)
{
    next unless $file =~ /.png$/;  ## entry must have .png extension
    my $genus = $file =~ s/\d*\.png$//r;
    push(@{$genus_species{$genus}}, $file);   ## push to array,the @{} is to cast the single entry to a reference to an list
}

for my $genus (keys %genus_species)
{
    print "$genus = ";
    print "$_ " for sort @{$genus_species{$genus}}; # sort and loop though entries in list reference
    print "\n";
}
```

Please advise how to output these variables in a **JSON** array. Thanks.

Update... Here's the revised script with the recommended changes per a forum member:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::PP;

use English;   ## use names rather than symbols for special variables

my $dir = '/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants';

opendir my $dfh, $dir  or die "Can't open $dir: $OS_ERROR";
my %genus_species;  ## store matching entries in a hash

for my $file (readdir $dfh)
{
    next unless $file =~ /.png$/;  ## entry must have .png extension
    my $genus = $file =~ s/\d*\.png$//r;
    push(@{$genus_species{$genus}}, $file);   ## push to array,the @{} is to cast the single entry to a reference to an list
}

print(encode_json(\%genus_species));
```

This revised code works! However, the file names are no longer sorted. Any ideas how to incorporate **sort** into the **encode_json** function?

Comment: Use a module e.g. Cpanel::JSON::XS

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but I don't know how to "use a module."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty straight forward actually... You can use the [JSON::PP module](https://perldoc.perl.org/JSON::PP) and pass a reference of your hash to `encode_json()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::PP;
# your other code goes here...

# instead of `for my $genus (keys %genus_species) { ... }` do:
print(encode_json(\%genus_species));
```

Comment: Okay I tried the code and got the error: untitled text 55:5: Can't locate JSON.pm in @INC (you may need to install the JSON module). However, earlier today I confirmed the I do have the JSON:: PP module installed on my Mac. Not sure what to do now!

Comment: @Jeff: JSON:PP works in the same way. See the edit.

Comment: Okay... inserted JSON::PP; and now I get syntax error lines 23 & 24, referring to: print "$genus = "; print "$_ " for sort @{$genus_species{$genus}};.... the error reads: Global symbol "$genus" requires explicit package.

Comment: Okay... removed everything below: print(encode_json(\%genus_species)); No errors now, but outputs only one variable. Not sure why... please advise. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff: Did you change anything how you create the hash? It should output the whole thing as JSON. If something is missing it's missing in the hash already.

Comment: Just posted my revised script with "sticky's" changes. The revision only outputs one variable. Not sure why.

Comment: Correction... "Sticky's" revision works! I didn't realized that ALL the variables are outputted on a single long line. The only issue now is to sort the file names numerically. Thanks for all your help, "sticky!"